# Power Query New column with Unique ID

Tags: database, powerquery, linked-tables

I have an excel power query that transforms new files when added to a folder.  The resultant table is then linked to a database.  I would like to create a new column in power query that creates a unique ID that will never change (Always assigned to the specific record) even when table gets appended by a query refresh.  The ID will serve as primary key in the linked database table.

The solutions that I'm trying either involve a concat of index and/or timenow functions, but these change every time the query is refreshed or resorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some non-changing columns, you could try to hash them into a unique ID such as

```
 = Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary(Text.Combine({[Column1],[Column2],[Column3]})))
```

or with

```
=  Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.ToList(Text.Combine({[Column1],[Column2],[Column3]})), each Text.From(Character.ToNumber(_))))
```

full sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Hash1 = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Hash", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.ToList(Text.Combine({[Column1],[Column2],[Column3]})), each Text.From(Character.ToNumber(_))))),
Hash2 = Table.AddColumn(Hash1, "Hash2", each Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary(Text.Combine({[Column1],[Column2],[Column3]}))))
in Hash2
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the dataset is large and there are rows with duplicate data.  These duplicates are not errors, so I need to generate the number without reference to column contents.  I will have rows with identical data, but each row needs a unique ID.

Comment: If the data just gets more and more rows but "sticks" in the same spot, you could use an index. If there were no duplicates you could use a hash. You can not assign a unique ID to a row in powerquery if the source data provides duplicate rows, and the contents of the rows and/or the sort order thereof changes each time you refresh. You would need to get a unique ID added at the source before powerquery gets it.  You could look into powerbi incremental refresh at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview